# number_format is rounding final decimal numbers and increasing to next round decimal number

Tags: php, decimal, rounding, number-formatting, decimal-point

I have a DOUBLE data type column in my MySQL table and I have a value of:

```
14.5299
```

But PHP `number_format` rounds that value to:

```
14.5300
```

And if I just `echo 14.5299`, it outputs:

```
14.53
```

How can I output `14.5299` without hardcoding anything in my HTML markup?

Comment: There's no such bug in the `number_format()` function, if that's your assumption. The issue is probably in the way you use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sprintf()`

```
echo sprintf("%2.4f", 14.5399);
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/sprintf

Comment: Just to clarify... `%2` means 2 digits ahead of the floating point `.4` is 4 digits after the point. So, you can adjust as needed. For example: %4.3f could be 3333.333.

Comment: This works fine... just like number_format() -- they're identical solutions.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
$double = 14.5299;
echo number_format(floor($double*100)/100, 2);
?>
```

Result is: 14.52

Comment: this is not what I want, I need four digits without rounding decimals.

Answer (score 2):

```
$double = 14.5299;
var_dump( number_format($double, 4, '.', ',') );
```

... prints:

```
string(7) "14.5299"
```

... as expected.

My educated guess is that your number has actually more 9's:

```
$double = 14.52999;
```

... in this case, `14.5300` is the correct way to round.

Answer (score 0):

The next function should works:

```
function fixedNumberFormat($float, $decimals, $withFormat = true) {
   $decPoint = ($withFormat) ? "," : null;
   $thousandsSep = ($withFormat) ? "," : null;
   return substr(number_format($float, $decimals + 1), 0, -1);
}

fixedNumberFormat(14.5299, 4);
```